# FabricJS 'freeDrawingBrush' not working on touchscreen

Tags: javascript, html, fabricjs, touchscreen

Code works fine on desktop but for some reason not on mobile (iOS or Android).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/4.0.0-beta.12/fabric.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    
    <body>
        <div class="canvas-container" style="width: 500px; height: 500px; position: relative; user-select: none;">
            <canvas id="c" width="500" height="500" style="border: 1px solid rgb(170, 170, 170);"></canvas>
        </div>

        <button id="clear" type="button">Clear</button>

        <script>
            // Free draw
            var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');
            canvas.freeDrawingBrush.width = 5;
            canvas.isDrawingMode = true;

            // Clear canvas
            document.getElementById('clear').addEventListener('click', function(){
                canvas.clear();
            })
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Code is based on this example which does work on mobile http://jsfiddle.net/MartinThoma/B525t/
I can see the canvas and button on mobile but touching the screen just moves the page!

Answer (score 0):

This is problem with `Fabric.js` build configurations, please check below documentation to enable `gestures control` in builder, as by default it's not added and `Fabric.js` does that by adding `Event.js` lib which depends on `"Interaction"` module.

Also do refer to this thread to get idea:
[Fabric.js Mobile Touch Issue](https://github.com/fabricjs/fabric.js/issues/6980)

And one more thing Fabric.js release the updated version with some additional touch screen issues fixed, please check with updating your lib.
[Fabric.js Changelog Version 5.0.0](http://fabricjs.com/changelog)

You can get the Fabric.js customized build from here as per your need:
[Fabric Get Build](http://fabricjs.com/build/)

Comment: Hi. I tried version 5.3.1 and custom build but still no joy?